# Subquery from the same table and relational data but in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "table1" with the following data.

| pk_id | sk_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 5 |

Like a node, each secondary key goes to its previous record, but within the same table. I had a stored procedure that disappeared from my files and now that I'm trying to rebuild it, there is no way that it returns the expected data. Its function was to receive a parameter and return all previous records that were linked to that record. For example, if it received the parameter 6, it would return the records 5,3,1 of the table "table1".

The subquery I currently have and it doesn't work is:

```
SELECT A.ipk_id, A.sk_id
FROM tabla1 AS A
WHERE (A.pk_id = 2
       OR EXISTS (
        SELECT B.pk_id
        FROM tabla1 AS B
        WHERE B.pk_id = A.sk_id
    )
);
```

Comment: which version of MySQL is the database?

Comment: The normal solution to this type of problem is a **recursive CTE**, but not all versions of MySQL can do this.

Comment: the version is 10.4.27-MariaDB @JuandelTrueno

Comment: @Joel, Before I had a code similar to the one I posted, and I think it's what I need for a stored procedure.

Comment: you may have used a stored procedure to do multiple selects in a loop; with recursive CTEs you no longer need to use a stored procedure for this

Answer (score 0):

```sql
set @pk_id = 6;

with recursive params as (
select pk_id, sk_id from tabla1 where pk_id = @pk_id
union all
select t.pk_id, t.sk_id
  from tabla1 t
  join params p
    on t.pk_id = p.sk_id)
select pk_id
  from params
 where pk_id <> @pk_id;
```

Outcome:

```
pk_id|
-----+
    5|
    3|
    1|
```

Comment: Hello @JHH, thank you very much for your collaboration, the query will work very well for me. However, more than the need to have that function, I wanted to remember one that I had created, it was without loops, it was just subqueries.